# Vue js loader override global css

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, vue-loader

I want to override the global css with the css defined in vue-loader component.

Currently I have this in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/styles.css">
</head>
<body id="the-dashboard">
<div id="app">

</div>


//......  Other Code Goes Here ......//
</body>
</html>
```

And in my vue component I have a scoped style:

```
<template>
  // ..... Some Code Here ..... //
</template>

<style scoped>
   // ... css code here ... //
</style>
<script>
   // ... script goes here ... //
</script>
```

What I want is that when this component is loaded, it should totally override the global css in index.html. Which is to say that it should behave in such a way that only scoped css should be the one that should apply to the whole body(the css imported in index.html should not at all be used).

Is that possible?

Comment: The `<style scoped>` should have done that? If your main css file classes are also present in `<style scoped>` It should have overridden?

Comment: It seems to override that. but many other properties defined in global css are present. Its not practical to override everything in scoped css @AmreshVenugopal

Comment: Oh, so you want only the styles present in scoped to take effect?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal yes exactly!

Comment: I seem to have a solution, not sure how bad it is. `import` a css reset file in your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

You can wrap all global styles in some selector, then refactor your HTML to your component don't be inside it.

```
.global {
  .someClass {
     ...
  }

  .another {

  }
}

<div class="global">
   <div class="someClass">
   ...
</div>

<component>
   <div class="someClass">
   ...
</component>
```

Or maybe you can try too to create an 'global' component, then inside it import the CSS using Sass `@import`, and it will be included inline. Then you put the tag as scoped (I'm not sure if this will work for children components inside it). That is:

```
<style scoped>
  @import 'build/main.css';
</style>
```

The best solution actually is: if you don't want that the CSS get global, then don't code it as global. Use classes instead generic tag names and attribute selectors.