# Vue & Tailwind - Ignore all global styles

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, tailwind-css

After trying different methods, I cannot get my vue **component(s) to ignore global CSS styles**.

The global styles have been defined by another developer and cannot be amended. Is there a way to specify the component to only used the styles within the scope of that component?

Dependant on `if` a condition is true, the user will see different versions of the app, which is why we do not want the global styles to apply... Not an ideal situation but hoping someone has a solution as I cannot get this to work. Thanks.

Resources:

[vue-js-loader-override-global-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502195/vue-js-loader-override-global-css)

[exclude-vue-component-from-stylesheet-of-existing-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61506302/exclude-vue-component-from-stylesheet-of-existing-application)

**UPDATE** -

[image]

[image]

Comment: the best solution would be to remove the style from the head with a if condition, i think the server has to do that, not your vue app

Comment: @Lk77 great, how would you go about that? I have updated the question with screenshots to help visualise - the style tag within the root component is where all the styles exist which need to be ignored

Comment: in that case i think you can't, i was thinking about an external stylesheet, the best solution would be to create an external scss file, and include it only when needed

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, thanks anyway!